# HttpClient with two handlers

Tags: c#

I have a server with multiple ip addresses. I want (1) to be able to make requests from all of that addresses and (2) automatically decompress responses. Here is what I came up with:

```
foreach (IPAddress ip in Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList)
{
    if (ip.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetwork) continue;
                              
    SocketsHttpHandler socketHandler = new();
    socketHandler.ConnectCallback = async (context, cancellationToken) =>
    {
        Socket socket = new(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ip, 0));
        socket.NoDelay = true;
        try
        {
            await socket.ConnectAsync(context.DnsEndPoint, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return new NetworkStream(socket, true);
        }
        catch
        {
            socket.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    };

    HttpClientHandler certHandler = new();
    certHandler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All;

    //the problem is below. How to put two handlers into HttpClient?
    HttpChainHandler handlers = new(socketHandler);
    handlers.InnerHandler = certHandler;
    clientsPool.Add(new HttpClient(handlers)); 
}
```

where HttpChainHandler is

```
public class HttpChainHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public HttpChainHandler(HttpMessageHandler handler) : base(handler)
    {

    }
}
```

This code doesn't work. I run a test app to https://api.myip.com and this site should return my ip address. All addresses are the same so my program make requests from a single ip-address.

However if I swap socketHandler with certHandler like this:

```
HttpChainHandler handlers = new(certHandler); //certHandler here instead of socketHandler
handlers.InnerHandler = socketHandler; //socketHandler here instead of certHandler
clientsPool.Add(new HttpClient(handlers));
```

then my requests are made from different ip. Finally! But... automatic decompression doesn't work! If I add headers to client DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br"); then
https://api.myip.com starts to answer with compressed responses.

So I can't have both socketHandler and certHandler in my HttpClient. In my attempt to combine them with DelegatingHandler whatever I put into its constructor doesn't work.

UPD:
I found a source code for DelegatingHandler. Everything you put into its constructor will be assigned to the property InnerHandler so it explains why my attempt to combine two handlers failed. Clearly I'm doing it wrong. The question remains: How to use two handlers with HttpClient?

Comment: possibly the same HttpClient is reused in stead of a new one selected from the pool.
I believe you can have named instances, so you have more control over which one to use - allowing for more desired behaviour through configuration

Comment: You have encryption and Compression (GZIP). The order of two when you send has to be the opposite of when you receive. So when you send you encrypt and then compress and when you receive you decompress and then decrypt (or opposite order).  You also have issues with TLS (which is automatic encryption with HTTPS). TCP is the transport layer for HTTP and when you use HTTPS (encryption) is done using TLS with TCP port 443.  GZIP is in the HTTP Header which is encrypted with HTTPS.  So automatic decompression will only work when TLS is also working. So I suspect TLS is not working when you fail.

Comment: Compressing an encrypted value is pointless, it won't save any space. It only makes sense to encrypt a compressed value not the other way round

Comment: @Stefan no, it's definitely not the case. I can see I use different HttpClients. Everything works one way or another. I can make requests from different ip or I can decompress responses. I just can't have it both.

Comment: @jdweng alas but looks like it's not the case. I can decompress just fine but can't do it from different ip addresses. Or I can make requests from different ip addresses but I can't decompress then. I have to make them work simultaneously: decompressing while making requests from different ips.

Comment: I think the TLS is failing and the connection is never completing.  I do not think it has anything to do with GZIP.

Comment: @jdweng I updated my post with findings of my misuse of DelegatingHandler. I don't know how to use it properly.

Comment: You cannot use UDP with TLS which is TCP.  if you are using UDP for transmitting the decrypted TLS that should be fine.  The question is the delegate sending the entire html (headers and body) or just the body?  Is the entire HTML being compressed or just one or more or the MIME attachments? See following which says it handles the transport layer.  Since Transport is TCP it is encrypted using TLS.  I have to think about this a little more. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpmessagehandler?force_isolation=true&view=net-6.0

Comment: I think you need to add two handlers (not one) : clientsPool.Add(new HttpClient(handlers));   The certificate is done before the request is sent using TLS and the handler is used to verify a specific certificate (or more than one) is chosen and reject connection if you do not want to use any certificates.  Then message is encrypted/decrypted with key in the certificate.  GZIP is done after the connection completes.  The certificate handler and the compression cannot be done at the same time.

Comment: @jdweng I removed custom certificate check from my code example so not to confuse anybody. My problem is I need to make requests from different ip addresses and be able to decompress responses. So basically my question is how to put both SocketsHttpHandler and HttpClientHandler into HttpClient.

Comment: Isn't the answer the same and add two handler rather than one handler.  Socket handler is taking the HTML message and packing/unpacking into one or more datagrams. GZIP compression is done with the body of entire HTML message. If you want the socket handler to do compression it would be with each datagram being individually compresses which is not what Accept-Encoding does. There are 3 specs HTTP 1.0 (stream), http 1.2 (chunk) and http 2.0. Not that familiar with 2.0.  See : https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-difference-between-http-12-20-versions-why-should-anand-bhagwat?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng that was my question in the first place: how to add two handlers? 

Comment: I said : I think you need to add two handlers (not one) : clientsPool.Add(new HttpClient(handlers));  So use two ADD statments.

Comment: Oh, I see... clientsPool is my variable. It's a List<HttpClient> clientsPool = new(); Every each of its item is added by me as shown in my code example. Later I select one item from that list and I expect it to be able to make a request from a certain ip-address and an ability to decompress the response. Using second Add statement won't help to achieve that goal.